# Bunit & Blazorise Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IComponentActivator' from singleton 'Bunit.Rendering.WebTestRenderer

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazorise, bunit

I am receiving this error to do a unit test with spec test and bunit  for a project in Blazor and Blazorise:

Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IComponentActivator' from singleton 'Bunit.Rendering.WebTestRenderer

Thi is the code of unit test:

```
using BlazorApp1.Pages;
using Blazorise;
using Blazorise.Bootstrap;
using Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome;
using Blazorise.Modules;
using Bunit;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Moq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class Feature1StepDefinitions
    {

        private IRenderedComponent<Home> _cut;
        private readonly TestContext _ctx;

        
        private readonly Mock<IClassProvider> _classProviderMock;

        public Feature1StepDefinitions()
        {
            
            _ctx = new TestContext();


            _ctx.Services.AddBlazorise(options =>
            {
            })
            .AddBootstrapProviders()
            .AddFontAwesomeIcons();
            _ctx.Services.AddSingleton<IJSUtilitiesModule, JSUtilitiesModule>();
        }

            [Given("a list of stores")]
        public void GivenTheComponentIsRendered()
        {
          
        }

        [When("the page is rendered")]
        public void GivenTheComponentIsRendered2()
        {
            /////In this line i receive the error!!!!!!!!!!!!
            _cut = _ctx.RenderComponent<Home>();
        }

        [Then("the stores are loaded")]
        public void ThenTheOnInitializedMethodShouldBeCalled()
        {
           
            //_cut.Instance.Stores.Should().NotBeNull();
            //_cut.Instance.Stores.Should().HaveCount(2);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the file Home.razor

```
@page "/"

@using Blazorise.DataGrid
@using BlazorApp1.Models
@using Blazorise.Components

<DataGrid TItem="StoresDatagrid" Data="@stores">
    <DataGridColumns>
        <DataGridColumn TItem="StoresDatagrid" Field="@nameof(StoresDatagrid.StoreCode)" />
        <DataGridColumn TItem="StoresDatagrid" Field="@nameof(StoresDatagrid.Name)" />
        <DataGridColumn TItem="StoresDatagrid" Field="@nameof(StoresDatagrid.IsEnabled)" />
    </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>
```

THis is the file Home.razor.cs

```
using BlazorApp1.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorApp1.Pages
{
    public partial class Home : ComponentBase
    {
        protected string test = "";
        protected List<StoresDatagrid> stores;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            test = "ruben";
            stores = GetStores();
        }

        private List<StoresDatagrid> GetStores()
        {
            return new List<StoresDatagrid>()
            {
                new StoresDatagrid
                {
                    StoreCode = 40055,
                    Name = "Store 1",
                    IsEnabled = true
                },
                new StoresDatagrid
                {
                    StoreCode = 40056,
                    Name = "Store 2",
                    IsEnabled = false
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Blazorise docs](https://blazorise.com/docs/usage):

> For testing purposes, there is currently an internal Blazorise Service that should be configured as Transient so the bUnit test engine does not throw an error. You should add this setup: ctx.Services.AddBlazorise().Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IComponentActivator, ComponentActivator>()); Other than that it should pretty much work out of the box. Let us know if you're having any difficulties. For some testing examples, you can look at some of our [tests](https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/tree/master/Tests/Blazorise.Tests).